# Clarification of Proof of Baby Rudin Theorem 4.2

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I'm a bit confused about the proof in Theorem 4.2 in Baby Rudin, and could use some help filling in the intermediate steps.

---

Theorem 4.2 states:
$$ \lim_{x\to p} f(x) = q \iff \lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) = q $$
for every sequence $\{p_n\} \subset E \text{ s.t. } p_n \to p, p_n \neq p$. [*]

---

The forward direction ($\implies$) is fairly straightforward, but the converse is a bit confusing. An outline of his proof by contraposition goes:

Suppose $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) \neq q$, then
$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall \delta > 0, \exists x \in E \text{ with } 0 < d_X(x, p) < \delta \text{ but } d_Y(f(x), q) \geq \epsilon $$

Take $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$, thus we find a sequence in $E$ that satisfies [*] above but $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) =q$ is false.

---

I'm assuming $\delta_n$ is supposed to be the radius of the neighborhood around $p$. But what is the sequence $p_n$ that satifies [*]? Furthermore we have not defined $f$ anywhere, how do we know $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) = q$ is false?

Comment: $E$ is the domain of $f$, i.e. $f : E \to Y$, where $E \subset X$, and $X, Y$ are metric spaces.

Comment: There isn't an explicit formula for such a sequence $p_n$, however, one can show that such a sequence must exist given what is stated. Indeed, for any specific $\delta$, a corresponding $x$ exists such that the inequalities are all satisfied. In particular, for $\delta=1$, one has a corresponding $x$ -- denote this $p_1$-- for $\delta=1/2$, there is $x$, i.e., $p_2$, etc.

Comment: Ah I see. Since the negation there says it holds for all $\delta > 0$, so it must hold for this specific $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then there exists some $x_n$ with $0 < d_X(x_n, p) < \delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$, which implies $x_n \to p$, which implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(p_n) = q$ is false.

Comment: Proofs by contraposition still feel strange to me. But thanks - that clarifies the proof for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is not defined. You still know however that, for some number $\varepsilon>0$, whenever $\delta>0$ there is some point $x\in E$ such that $0<d_X(x,p)<\delta$ and $d_Y\bigl(f(x),q\bigr)\geqslant\varepsilon$. In particular, if $n\in\Bbb N$, there is some $p_n\in E$ such that $0<d_X(p_n,p)<\frac1n$ and $d_Y\bigl(f(p_n),q\bigr)\geqslant\varepsilon$. Now, it follows from the fact that you have $0<d_X(p_n,p)<\frac1n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=p$. And it follows from the fact that $d_Y\bigl(f(p_n),q\bigr)\geqslant\varepsilon$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ that you *don't* have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=q$.

Comment: Hello, can I further ask why we require $p_n\neq p$? If we drop this condition, does the theorem still hold?

Comment: I see, $p$ is a limit point of $E$ which means $p$ might not be inside the set $E$.